# Can excel add-in work with Azure AD B2C authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, excel-addins

Excel add-ins can work well with Azure AD. I haven't found any docs regarding integration add-in with Azure AD B2C. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

B2C SSO to customer owned apps within the Azure AD B2C tenants is supported. SSO to Office 365 or to other Microsoft and non-Microsoft SaaS apps is not supported. Please refer the document for more information

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/compare-with-b2c